# Batch check if last printed line contains a word

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have 2 batch files a.bat and b.bat. a.bat calls b.bat and b.bat prints a sentence to the screen. How can I check that sentence to see if it contains a word and if it contains a set it as a variable. For example

```
Sentance: Hello, how are you today?
If %Sentance contains% Hello set var=Hello
If %Sentance contains% Hi set var=hi
```

### There may be more than one Sentance on the screen so I want to check the most recently displayed sentance.

Here's what I have.

```
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ('b.bat') do set lastline=%%i
set "var="
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hi\>">nul && set "var=hi"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO NEXT0) ELSE (GOTO FOUND)
:NEXT0
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hello\>">nul && set "var=hello"
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (GOTO NEXT1) ELSE (GOTO FOUND)
:NEXT1
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hola\>">nul && set "var=hola"
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (GOTO NEXT2) ELSE (GOTO FOUND)
:found
echo %var%
pause
```

The code doesn't work if the last line is something like "this is a message hello"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo the string and search for the keyword:

```
set sentence=Hello, how are you?
echo %sentence%|findstr /i "\<hello\>">nul && set "var=Hello"
echo %sentence%|findstr /i "\<hi\>">nul && set "var=Hi"
```

`\<` and `\>` means "Word boundaries", this avoids false positives (C**hi**nese, C**hello**,...)

`>nul` redirects the found string to nirvana to keep the screen clear.

`&&` executes the `set` command only, if previous command (`findstr`) was successful.

**Edit**

Based on your last comment, I understand: `a.bat` calls `b.bat`. `b.bat` writes several lines, and `a.bat` wants to get the last of them (I hope, I got that right).

to get the last line of `b.bat`, use:

```
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ('b.bat') do set lastline=%%i
echo you said: %lastline%
set "var="
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hello\>">nul && set "var=Hello"
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hi\>">nul && set "var=Hi"
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hola\>">nul && set "var=Hola"
echo/%var%
```

But there is a little problem: `for` captures the output of `b.bat` instead of showing it to the screen. (Especially the prompt of  `set /p` - so you don't know, when or what to input). To work around that, force `b.bat` to write to screen (`>con` writes directly to screen). So basically, `b.bat` should look like this:

```
@echo off
echo this line gets captured by a.bat
>con echo this line goes directly to screen
>con set /p "input=give me input: "
echo something about %input%.
```

Note: I used the `eol`-trick from aschipfl's answer, because (although it looks ugly) this works even for both `"` and `;`, which are problematic with the "standard way" (`"delims= eol="`). Of course this still isn't foolproof (for example `&` still makes problems)

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question about this though if I don't know what the sentance is, is there a way to find out what the sentance is?

Comment: It's stored in `%sentence%` - but that'  so obvious that I'm not sure, I understand you right.

Comment: Yes I know you stored the sentance in the variable %sentance% but my original code has a few hundred sentances I don't want to have to add set sentance= to all of them

Comment: They are produced by `b.bat`, and should be processed by `a.bat`, right?

Comment: A.bat calls b.bat and it generates a sentance based on the input so without knowingwhat that input is can I set the last sentance that was displayed as %sentance%? Sorry for not responding for a while.

Comment: @jonathanx see my edit (I hope I understood you right)

Comment: Yay what you have works but with one problem when I have it search for six different words it always sets the variable to the last one.

Comment: For example <br/>                                                                                                 echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hello\>">nul && set "var=Hello" <br/> echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hi\>">nul && set "var=Hi" <br/> echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hola\>">nul && set "var=hola" the <br/> is supposed to be a line break

Comment: what do you want it to be? The first? A random one?

Comment: Which ever one it contains the sentance should only contain one of the words I'm looking for.

Comment: probably a relict of the previous run. Try my edited `a.bat`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work; I posted what i have in my question.

Comment: you use `errorlevel wrong. Try this instead: `echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hello\>">nul && (set "var=Hello" & goto :found)` . And you don't need `goto next` because it goes there anyway.

Comment: I tried `code echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hola\>">nul && (set "var=hola" & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :found)
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hi\>">nul && (set "var=hi" & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :found)
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hello\>">nul && (set "var=hello" & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :found) `code but it sets %var% as hello.

Comment: a) you don't need the errorlevel, b) it's the errorlevel of the last command - `set` here, not `find`.

Comment: `echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hello\>">nul && (set "var=hello" & goto :found)
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hi\>">nul && (set "var=hi" & :found)
echo %lastline%|findstr /i "\<hola\>">nul && (set "var=hola" & goto :found)` doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36236765) already shows how to find specific words in the output of the called batch file `b.bat`.

To check the output of `b.bat` in the caller `a.bat`, you can do the following:

Supposing `b.bat` contains the following:

```
echo Hello, how are you?
```

`a.bat` might look like this:

```
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('
    b.bat ^| findstr /I /R /C:"\<hello\>" /C:"\<hi\>"
') do (
    set "FOUND=%%L"
)
```

This pipes the output of `b.bat` into `findstr`, which uses multiple search strings, then its output is captured by a `for /F` loop, which assigns the output to the variable `FOUND`.

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner but is there a way to set found to equal hi or hello depending on which it found rather than the entire line?

Comment: `findstr` is not capable of returning only the matching string portion, it always returns the full line containing a match; you could work around that by using something like: `b.bat | > nul findstr /I /R /C:"\<hello\>" && set "FOUND=hello"`, and the same for the search word `hi`; as you can see, you need to assign `hello` explicitly, so it is not extracted from the original string; this means that `FOUND` does not contain the word `hello` in the same case (upper-/lower-case, mixed) as in the original line...

Answer (score 1):

```
Echo off
:Loop
    Set /p Input=%CD%^>
    rem Show what the user typed
    Echo %Input%
    rem Execute user's typed command
    %Input%
    rem Get first word and rest of line
    for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ("%input%") do echo %%A AND %%B
Goto Loop
```

Which gets what the user typed and mimics cmd processing (press Ctrl + C to stop it). Use set to manipulate the text.

You can use a `for` loop to break up text.