# How to check for certain text input in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that lets the user type in something then takes what they typed in and puts it as a value, let's say the value is called **`%input%`**.

I want the batch file to check for certain words in the **`%input%`** value and then use the **`goto`** command.

Anyone got any solutions?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is some code that I am using:

```
@echo off
title Test
:Loop
Set /p Input=""
if "%input%"=="word *" goto function
```

I just need help figuring out how to check for **`"word"`** in the **`%input%`** value.

Hopefully this clears some things up.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36236765/2152082) should be easy to adapt to your needs (just process the variable instead of reading the last line of a file)

Comment: Please edit your question and post some code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try for this code :

```
@echo off
:MainLoop
Color 0B
Cls
set /p "Input=Type something here "
echo %Input%|findstr /i "\<hello\>">nul && goto HelloFunction || goto NoHelloFunction

:HelloFunction
cls
Color 0A
echo I am into The Hello Function
pause
Goto MainLoop

:NoHelloFunction
cls
Color 0C
echo I am not into the Hello Function
pause
Goto MainLoop
```

**Explanation**

**`\<`** and **`\>`** means *"Word boundaries"*, this avoids false positives (**Hello**o, C**hello**,...)

**`>nul`** redirects the found string to nul to keep the screen clear.

**`&&`** executes the set command only, if previous command **`(findstr)`** was successful.

**`||`** means else and goto to another function